# Send massive PEC (certified email) with mailgun or other mailing service

Tags: mailgun, mailing-list

I'm using **mailgun** to send massive email.
Now, I need to send massive [PEC (certified email)](https://vademecumitalia.com/pec-what-is-it-why-should-you-need-a-pec-address-and-how-to-get-one/) and I would like to do with **mailgun**. 
1. Do you know if it is possible?
2. Do you know if there is a mailing service that can do this?
3. Have someone send massive PEC?
Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SHORT ANSWER***:

**It is possible but only if you have a PEC on your domain (info@pec.yourdomain.com)**

---

***LONG ANSWER***:

To send massive emails with Mailgun you need to set up a domain *(eg. yourdomain.com or mailer.yourdomain.com)* and make changes to DNS. After that you can set up SMTP credentials.

So even if you can theoretically set up SMTP credentials for a certified PEC mail, the problem with Mailgun is related to the domain.

If you have a PEC on your domain (info@pec.yourdomain.com) you can set up your domain and mailgun can send mass mail even with PEC.

If instead you have a standard PEC (eg nomecognome@pec.it) you can't send mass mail with mailgun because you can't setup domains as pec.it.

Comment: can you please reference some documentation that describes how this would be set up once I have a custom domain.